# Skip weekend and public holidays when calculating duration between 2 datefields

Tags: python, django, datefield

I have 2 `DateField` in my form, `start_date` and `end_date` and a `FloatField` called `duration`. I figure out how to automatically save the duration without user input by calculating the duration of start and end date, but how can i give a condition to skip weekend, and any particular public holiday?

model.py:

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    duration = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

form.py:

```
class LeavesDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leave
        fields = ('employee', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'duration')
        widgets = {'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                   'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                   'employee': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'duration': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

view.py:

```
def my_leaves_view(request):
    """
   My Leaves view
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    form = LeavesDetailForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            inst = form.save(commit=False)
            inst.start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            inst.end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            duration = (inst.end_date - inst.start_date).days
            inst.duration = duration
            inst.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/hrm/employee/leaves')
    return render(request, 'hrm/employee/details/my_leaves.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution can be to use `numpy`'s [`busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html#numpy.busday_count) function:

```
import numpy as np


def my_leaves_view(request):
    ...
    inst.duration = np.busday_count(inst.start_date, inst.end_date)
    ...
```

Which gives exactly the days count without weekends and holidays.